# C++ How to convince constexpr function to be constexpr, for any kind of argument

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, constant-expression

I could not find a relevant question/answer for this one. Consider this:

```cpp
// constexpr declares intent
template <typename T> inline constexpr const bool probe (T const &) noexcept { return false; }
template <typename T> inline constexpr const bool probe (T const *) noexcept { return true; }
template <typename T> inline constexpr const bool probe (T &&) noexcept = delete ;
template <typename T> inline constexpr const bool probe (T) noexcept = delete ;
```

As we all know and expect the following do work as expected, at compile time:

```cpp
constexpr inline const char * holla_ = "Hola!";
// OK
static_assert(probe(holla_));
// OK
static_assert(probe("string literal"));
```

And these too:

```cpp
inline const char buff[]{"ABCD"};
// OK -- although `buff` is not compile time array
static_assert(probe(buff));

constexpr inline int const * ip = nullptr ;
static_assert(probe(ip));
```

But here is the, compile time no-can-do area:

```cpp
// deliberately omitted constexpr
inline const char * wot_here_ = "Another literal";

// error: the value of 'wot_here_' is not usable in a 
// constant expression
// note: 'wot_here_' was not declared 'constexpr'
// static_assert(probe(wot_here_));
```

I understand `wot_here_` is the runtime variable. `probe()` is declared and implemented with argument types only. Am I openly going against some obvious rule in the standard? Or subtly, against a few subtle ones.

I am cautiously hoping someone can sort of, "get around" this issue?

[Code is here](https://godbolt.org/g/6PgB13)

Comment: You seem to have omitted the definition of `wot_here_`

Comment: `std::is_pointer_v<decltype(wot_here_)>`

Comment: Strictly speaking, `const char* wot_here_ = "Another literal";` may change its value at run-time. (Qualifiers don't forbid this.) Did you test with `const char *const wot_here_ = "Another literal";` as well?

Comment: Tried by myself: `const char *const` doesn't fix it.

Comment: @rubenvb, yes thanks, rectified that

Comment: you've added `constexpr` everywhere, but not for `wot_here_`: https://godbolt.org/g/c2iypL

Comment: You can't enforce it.

Comment: Why do you need overloads for both `T` and `T&&`? Isn't `T&&` enough?

Answer (score 2):

> I am really hoping someone can sort-of-a, "get around" this issue?

The only "get around" I see is declate `wot_her_` `constexpr`.

If you define

```
inline const char * wot_here_ = "Another literal";
```

you have a variable that is initialized run-time.

Observe that `const char *` is a variable pointer to a constant `char`, so isn't a constant value because you can incerement/decrement it.

A `constexpr` function can be also called by a run-time variable, so you can call

```
probe( wot_here_)
```

but `probe()`, in this case, is executed run-time.

The problem is that `static_assert()` is executed necessarily compile-time, so

```
static_assert( probe( wot_here_) );
```

gives error because the compiler can't check compile time something that is executed run-time.

The only solution that I see is define `wot_here_` `constexpr`, as `holla_` before, so the compiler can execute compile-time the `probe(wot_here_)` inside the `static_assert()`.

Comment: There is more to it, otherwise `const char *const` would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to declare the pointer parameter of `probe` as a reference such that no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is required:

```
template <typename T> inline constexpr const bool probe (T const * &) noexcept { return true;  }
                                                                // ^
// this one is required to accept holla_, which is of type char const * const
template <typename T> inline constexpr const bool probe (T const * const &) noexcept { return true;  }

// this one is required to accept buff, which is an array
template <typename T, std::size_t N> inline constexpr const bool probe (T const (&)[N]) noexcept { return true;  }

// the other three overloads keep the same
template <typename T> inline constexpr const bool probe (T const &) noexcept { return false; }
template <typename T> inline constexpr const bool probe (T &&) noexcept = delete ;
template <typename T> inline constexpr const bool probe (T) noexcept = delete ;
```